# Error using strtok and arrays

Tags: c++, strtok

I'm trying to split a string and put the result into an array using `strtok` and `strncpy`, but when the code runs, it throws an error.

Code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{    
    char str[] ="( 6 + 2 )";
    char *pch;
    int i = 0;

    pch = strtok(str, " ");  

    while (pch != NULL)
    {
         printf("%s\n", pch);     
         pch = strtok (NULL, " ");  
         i = i + 1;
    }

    char arreglo[i];

    strncpy(arreglo, pch, sizeof(arreglo));

    cin.get();
}
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do in `strncpy( arreglo, pch, sizeof(arreglo) );`.

Comment: and what error are You getting? At first glance, You're expecting that half of the code is being executed during compilation.

Comment: Im trying to divide the string (6+2) into an array  like:  arreglo[0] = (, arreglo[1] = 6, ...., the function strtok divide the (6+2) into tokens like (,6,+,2,), so I assumed that with strnpy I could do that but i cant G_G, the error is that the console stops working

Comment: You're going wrong using 40-year old technology. Why not the C++ standard library, invented almost 20 years ago?

Comment: Why tag this as C++ when you aren't using any of the features C++ offers?

Comment: Since your tag is C++, prefer using `std::string` and it's `find` methods.  Remember, that `strtok` modifies the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
strncpy( arreglo, pch, sizeof(arreglo) );
```

This statement gives a **Segmentation Fault** because `pch` is `NULL`.

Comment: Dereferencing a null pointer is not guaranteed to lead to a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet

```
char arreglo[i];

strncpy( arreglo, pch, sizeof(arreglo) );
```

makes no sense.

First of all there is no variable length arrays in C++. So it is better not to use such an extension of the compiler.

Secondly after exiting the preceeding loop `pch` is equal to NULL. And moreover this statement

```
strncpy( arreglo, pch, sizeof(arreglo) );
```

does not do what you want.

I think you mean something like the following

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

//...

std::vector<std::string> v;

pch = strtok( str, " " );  

while ( pch != NULL )
{
         printf ("%s\n",pch);     
         v.push_back( pch );
         pch = strtok( NULL, " " );  
}
```